# Update file in folder inside the s3bucket python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a folder inside the s3 bucket i need to update the file inside the existing folder
using python can any one assist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my own question. The code below works perfectly
from my local folder. I opened the folder and and use 'rb' (read binary) to store file.

```
s3 = boto3.client(
    's3', 
    region_name='ap-south-1', 
    aws_access_key_id = S3_access_key, 
    aws_secret_access_key=S3_secret_key
)
path_data=os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, "screenShots",folder_name)
dir=os.listdir(path_data)
for file in dir:
    with open(path_data+"/"+file, 'rb') as data:
        s3.upload_fileobj(data, s3_Bucket_name, folder_name+"/"+file)
shutil.rmtree(path_data)
```